# Black faces when rendered

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
     Hey guys! I just started using Blender 2.76b and I'm encountering an issue when I render. I have a mesh and a light source set up but when I render, some faces appear black. I've done some research and found out about normals but when I checked, they all seemed to be facing the right way. Any help would be appreciated, here's a link to the .blend file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ebmmcrlc1gfce2/castle.blend?dl=0

Comment: Your light source seems to be directed down while you want it to light a castle, so rotate it towards the object. .

Comment: Mr Zak - It looks like that but I'm using a sun lamp that's positioned in front of the castle. Even with a spot lamp pointing directly at the wall, the render remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your scene, you need to select the sun lamp and press R to rotate it. Rotate the sun lamp to point the light in your desired direction, and try rendering again.

Comment: I was just looking at different light properties when I saw this comment, that's exactly the case! Thank both you and Mr Zak for helping me out!